# How to make Dropzone.js appear like the theme on the site?

Tags: javascript, css, dropzone.js

I've been trying to make Dropzone.js look like the theme on the site (dropzonejs.com) using a short piece of example code and dropzone.css. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropzone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">
</head>
<form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone"></form>
</html>
```

I checked the file paths, and those are all good. The end result looks like 
http://www.dropzonejs.com/examples/simple.html but my intended result is like the example on the main page "Try It!" section.

Let me know if you can help.

Comment: if you `click right> inspect element` you will the `.css` they use, just copy paste it also i don't see t the "try it section" can you point me please the link

Comment: If you look under the "try it!" section you will see an implementation of Dropzone, I want the style of that Dropzone.

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ the Try It Out section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the theme itself, it seems to work fine as long as you follow the same structure in the `css` rules: `main section .dropzone`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropzone.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <section>
                 <h1 id="try-it-out">Try it out!</h1>

                <div id="dropzone">
                    <form action="" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="demo-upload">
                        <div class="dz-message">Drop files here or click to upload.
                            <br> <span class="note">(This is just a demo dropzone. Selected files are <strong>not</strong> actually uploaded.)</span>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure you have both `css` files in your example

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnoxvc7t/

Comment: Tried it out, still no luck, just a generic version. Could you zip up the code you used and share the link? Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. Silly me, just some bad HTML. Thanks alot!

Comment: FYI: Your JS Fiddle doesn't work. Dragging a file results in the browser opening the file.

Comment: Indeed, this looks quite broken before I even tried it.

Comment: I'm finding that I need to specify an actual path for `action=` for this to work.